# Can't connect to a particular wifi network ? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, networkmanager

I have been having some issues when the wifi to a particular wifi connection just stopped working.
I have a dual boot OS with Windows and Ubuntu 18.04.

Let's say I have two wifi connections - wifi1 and wifi2:

- I have checked the password - it is valid.
- Power management is disabled on the Ubuntu 18.04 OS.
- Can successfully connect to wifi1. Checked another computer
  with 18.04 OS with connections to wifi1 and wifi2 and they seem to
  work fine.
- When booting up in Windows, one can connect to both wifi1 and
  wifi2.  Forgot the network and tried to reconnect again but it did
  not work .

As it is able to connect to other wifi connections, something like corrupt file system, I guess is ruled out.
It seems to be a very peculiar issue and I am a bit clueless what could be the reason.

Comment: Does the wifi connection have a SSID with non-ascii characters in it?

Comment: No , it doesnt . It just consists of usual english letter characters